# Call mvn tomcat:run in multiple projects/different directories using a batch file

Tags: windows, maven, batch-file, tomcat, cmd

I am new to batch files. 
I have two projects and I want to run them using a batch file.
projectA should run on port 8081 and projectB on 8082. I have tried the following 2 approaches, but only projectA starts on port 8081.

```
@echo off
SET CMB_HOME=C:\Development\CMB
cd %CMB_HOME%\projectA\
call mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8081

cd %CMB_HOME%\projectB\
call mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8082
```

Seems like the following part is not read.

```
cd %CMB_HOME%\projectB\
call mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8082
```

I have also tried creating 2 batch files: master.bat and slave.bat.

master.bat contains the following and is calling slave.bat:

```
@echo off
SET CMB_HOME=C:\Development\CMB
cd %CMB_HOME%\projectA\
call mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8081

SET SCRIPT_HOME=C:\Development\scripts\CMB
cd %SCRIPT_HOME%
call slave.bat
```

And slave.bat contains the following:

```
@echo off
SET CMB_HOME=C:\Development\CMB
cd %CMB_HOME%\projectB\
call mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8082
```

Please help.

Comment: `call` won't return until called process exits. So I suppose `mvn` is a process still running. Use `start` command instead. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: Updated passing arguments.

```
@echo off
SET CMB_HOME=C:\Development\CMB

pushd %CMB_HOME%\projectA\
start "Port 8081" cmd /c "mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8081"
popd

pushd %CMB_HOME%\projectB\
start "Port 8082" cmd /c "mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8082"
popd
```

as I don't know how mvn expect its arguments you may play with the quotes in the start command

```
start "Port 8081" cmd/c ^""mvn "tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8081" ^"
...
start "Port 8082" cmd/c ^""mvn "tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8082" ^"
```

Or try a workaround...

```
@echo off

if "%~1" neq "" goto run

start "Port 8081" cmd /c ^""%~f0" projectA 8081 ^"
start "Port 8082" cmd /c ^""%~f0" projectB 8082 ^"
goto :eof

:run 
set "PORT=%~2"
set "CMB_HOME=C:\Development\CMB\%~1\"
pushd %CMB_HOME%
call mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=%PORT%
popd
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
However, it won't work with "-Dmaven.tomcat.port={port}"
I have to remove that and update projectA and projectB poms and add the following tag in the tomcat maven plugin configuration.

`<port>{port for project here}</port>`

Is there anyway I could avoid this pom update and set the port in the batch file instead?